# Find the sum of this series of coefficients of $(1+x+x^2)^n$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If 
$$
(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_rx^r
$$
then find the sum of :
$$
a_0^2-a_1^2+a_2^2 +.....+(-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}^2=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{r-1}a_r^2
$$
in terms of $a_n$ and $n$.

What I've done :
I've tried replacing $x$ with $\frac{-1}{x}$ and then multiplying the resultant series with the original series. However, this proved long and tedious and I gave up. Is there any other method to solve this question ? The answer given in my textbook is $\frac{a_n(1-(-1)^na_n)}{2}$. However I believe this answer to be wrong since the previous owner has written so in the margin.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that the $a's$ have the following symmetry $a_{2n-r}=a_r$

\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x+x^2)^n =\sum_{r=0}^{2n} a_r x^{r}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute $x=-x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (1-x+x^2)^n =\sum_{r=0}^{2n} (-1)^r a_r x^{r}
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply these two equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (1+x^2+x^4)^n =\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Now consider the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ ... we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 a_n = 2\sum_{r=0}^{2n} (-1)^r a_r^2 +(-1)^n a_n^2
\end{eqnarray*}
So the answer in the book is right  ... The answer is $\frac{a_n(1-(-1)^n a_n)}{2}$.

Comment: How do we prove that $a_{2n-r}=a_r$ ?

Comment: Substitute $x=1/x$ and multiply by $x^{2n}$. This will cause the series to reverse.

Comment: So we get the same series... Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: Try a few examples with small numbers $n$ and you will find that the answer in the book is correct and that this answer is wrong. E.g. $n=4$, $(a_r) = (1,4,10,16,19,16,10,4,1)$. You get $1^2-4^2+10^2-16^2 = -171 = \frac{19(1-19)}{2}$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier ... goodness me, you are absolutely right ... I missed a square on the second $a_n$ ... I will edit now .... thank you.

Comment: Nicely done.  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV Wow, cool ... Thank you.